# Generic output operator overloading with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Given an abstract base class `Object` and 2 derived classes, `Person` and `Gathering`. Where `Gathering` is a data structure which stores pointers to `Person` or other `Gathering` pointers inside of an array.

I would like to override the output operator so it prints any type of `Object`. But I do not know how to override the operator properly so when it receives type `Object` it knows how to deal with it.

Here is a simple code that exemplifies what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#import <iostream>
#import <cstring>

class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object(){};
};

class Person : public Object {
private:
    char * m_name;
public:
    Person(char * input) {
        m_name = new char[strlen(input)];
        strncpy(m_name, input, strlen(input));
    }

    char* getName() const{
        return m_name;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person* p) {
        os << p->getName();
        return os;
    }
};

class Gathering : public Object {
private:
    int m_size;
    Object* m_buffer;

public:
    Gathering() : m_size(10) 
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Gathering* v) {
        for (int i=0; i<v->getSize(); i++) {
            //Trying to send Object to outputstream..
            os << "[" << v->getBuffer()[i] << "]";
        }
    }

    int getSize() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    Object* getBuffer() const {
        return m_buffer;
    }
};
```

I am very aware of what the problem is, how do Ideal with this? Any references or pointers are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a virtual member function in `Object`, call it in your operator overload and implement it correctly for children classes.

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object(){}

    virtual void print(std::ostream&){}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Object& obj) {
        obj.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

class Gathering : public Object {
private:
    int m_size;
    Object* m_buffer;

public:
    Gathering() : m_size(10) 
    {}

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) {
        for (int i=0; i<v->getSize(); i++) {
            os << "["; 
            m_buffer[i].print(os);
            os << "]";
        }
    }

    int getSize() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    Object* getBuffer() const {
        return m_buffer;
    }
};
```

Also not related, but put a virtual destructor in your children classes, use a vector instead of your `Object` pointer `m_buffer` or at least initialise it in your constructor, but i guess you have school restrictions or something :)

Comment: Very well. I will give this a try and report in.